# iPhone dev get contents of C array in different class

Tags: c

I have a c array:

```
CGPoint hillKeyPoints[kMaxHillKeyPoints];
```

How do I access this from another class?

If I had an `NSArray` I would use a pointer to access the array, ie:

```
hillClass.[hillKeypoints objectAtIndex:0];
```

How does this work in c?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't have classes.  C just has structures and ordinary functions.  Access is straightforward using one of the structure member access operators `.` or `->` (depending on whether or not you have a pointer) and the array subscripting operator `[]`:

```
typedef struct HillStruct
{
    CGPoint hillKeyPoints[kMaxHillKeyPoints];
} HillStruct;

void SomeFunction(HillStruct *hillStruct)
{
    // Read first member of the array in the structure
    CGPoint firstPoint = hillStruct->hillKeyPoints[0];
    // etc.
}
```